# Trying to change tabpage text, getting different results depending on location of code

Tags: c#

I am trying to update the text on a tab. I am utilizing a usercontrol to house the various controls so it can be easily added to each new tab. textBox1 also contains ghost text. Just gray text that says *Enter Name* that gets wiped when you click into the textbox.

When I try to update the text while using a button and text box located in the usercontrol, I am getting a **System.NullReferenceException**

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form = new Form1();
        form.tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text = textBox1.Text;
    }
```

I also am getting a **System.NullReferenceException** if I try to get the information to a messagebox.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form = new Form1();
        MessageBox.Show(form.tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text);
    }
```

but when I use a button on the main form, it **DOES NOT** give me the **System.NullReferenceException**. It performs the desired action but it pulls the wrong text. It keeps changing the selectedtab text to *Enter Name* no matter what you type into the textbox.

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl control= new UserControl();
        tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text = control.textBox1.Text;
    }
```

I also double checked that it is pulling the correct information with a messagebox and I have no issues when the button is on the main form.

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text);
    }
```

Here is a small project that shows what I am talking about. https://github.com/hangmanmatt/tabnametest.git

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Progman I tried reading through that before posting but I couldn't figure out how it would solve my problem, especially considering that the location of the button initiating the action changes entirely what happens.

Comment: You'll need to provide more code for folks to help you out. Without knowing how you constructed your forms and controls it's not possible to tell where the null reference is coming from. Checkout [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Sal I recreated an example that shows exactly what I am talking about. The link is at the end of the main post. It creates a new tab. When you use the button in the usercontrol, you get System.NullReferenceException but when you use the button on the main form, it doesn't give that message and just renames the tab to the ghost text no matter what you type into the text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke with my friend who is a professional programmer and he fixed my issue.

First was flipping the order of when I call a new tabpage and when I call the usercontrol

```
        private void NewTabButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage newTabPage = new TabPage("new tab");
        
        UserControl1 usercontrol = new UserControl1(newTabPage);
        
        usercontrol.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        
        newTabPage.Controls.Add(usercontrol);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(newTabPage);
    }
```

The second was making some changes to how I called the main form from my usercontrol

```
    public TabPage OwningTabPage;
    public UserControl1(TabPage owningTabPage)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        OwningTabPage = owningTabPage;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OwningTabPage.Text = textBox1.Text;
    }
```

Both changes were implemented into my main project and solve the issue perfectly.